# create list of range of indexes based on length of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with say 100 rows. I want to create a list of indexes based on N value.

For example:

If N value is given as 10, then I want to create 10 bucket list somewhat like below:

```
list = [(0,10), (10, 20), (20, 30)........(90, 100)]
```

If N =2

```
list = [(0,50), (50, 100)]
```

Comment: Your last list doesn't really follow the pattern of the rest...

Comment: `[[i, i+10] for i in range(0,100,10)]`?

Comment: Also what should happen if N is 18 and doesn't evenly divide the size of your DataFrame?